# Standalone Consumer throwing InvalidGroupIdException

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

This is a two part question.

I. The code is:

```
import java.time.Duration
import java.util
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, KafkaConsumer}
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import io.StdIn._

object StandaloneConsumer {
  private final var topics = ""
  private final val BOOTSTRAPSERVERS = "hostname:9092"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAPSERVERS)
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false: java.lang.Boolean)
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringDeserializer])
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringDeserializer])

    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)
    topics = readLine("Enter the topic name: ")

    try {
      val partitionInfos = consumer.partitionsFor(topics)
      val topicPartitions = new util.ArrayList[TopicPartition]
      if(partitionInfos != null) {
        for (partitionInfo <- partitionInfos.asScala) {
          topicPartitions.add(new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic, partitionInfo.partition))
        }
        consumer.assign(topicPartitions)
        while (true) {
          val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500))
          for(record <- records.asScala) {
            println(s"key = ${record.key}, value = ${record.value()}")
          }
          consumer.commitAsync()
        }
      }
    } catch {
      case e:Exception => e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
      consumer.commitSync()
      consumer.close()
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this **it is consuming all the data properly** but at the end it gives:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid group.id in the consumer configuration.
```

this error. **Why?**

II. I didn't understand this part of the code. What is going on?:

```
val topicPartitions = new util.ArrayList[TopicPartition]
  if(partitionInfos != null) {
    for (partitionInfo <- partitionInfos.asScala) {
      topicPartitions.add(new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic, partitionInfo.partition))
    }
```

Can somebody please explain this to me.
Thank you.

Comment: What's not clear about the error? You've never set up `GROUP_ID_CONFIG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kafka, committing does only make sense if you're part of a consumer group ( and then let Kafka cluster coordinators manage partition assignment and offset fetching/committing operations).
Regarding your code, it looks like you're doing manual partition assignment, but still you're trying to commit:

```
          consumer.commitAsync()
```

Some documentation on consumer group :

https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

For your question II

This code is fetching the different partition belonging to your topic and then you assign those partitions to your consumer.

You should read a bit more about Kafka consumer groups, and be sure , or not, if you want to use it , or handling partitions assignment on your own.
I would highly recommend using it ( for scalability purposes) except if you really want to skip it.